# Kubenetes: change hpa min-replica

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I have Kubernetes cluster hosted in Google Cloud. I created a deployment and defined a hpa rule for it:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment my_deployment --min 6 --max 30 --cpu-percent 80
```

I want to run a command that editing the `--min` value, **without remove and re-create a new hpa rule**. Something like:

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment my_deployment --min 1 --max 30
Error from server (AlreadyExists): horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "my_deployment" already exists
```

Is this possible to edit hpa (min, max, cpu-percent, ...) on command line?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is this possible to edit hpa (min, max, cpu-percent, ...) on command line?

They are editable just as any other resource is, though either `kubectl edit hpa $the_hpa_name` for an interactive edit, or `kubectl patch hpa $the_hpa_name -p '{"spec":{"minReplicas": 1}}'` for doing so in a "batch" setting.

If you don't know the `$the_hpa_name`, you can get a list of them like any other resource: `kubectl get hpa`, and similarly you can view the current settings and status with `kubectl get -o yaml hpa $the_hpa_name` (or even omit `$the_hpa_name` to see them all, but that might be a lot of text, depending on your cluster setup).

Comment: patch command worked for me, thanks